# Network connection prompt loops when my android app attempts to connect to specified network

Tags: android, kotlin, network-programming

I am new to android development and am attempting to create a simple example app that connects to a specified network when a button is pressed.

I have found a few examples of other questions but they are using the now deprecated `WifiManager.addNetwork()`

Currently when I test locally on my Huawei P20 (Android Version 10) a connection prompt pops up, scans for and finds the correct network, I connect, gives "Connection Successful" message, then prompt pops up again and repeats and repeats and repeats...

With "verbose" debugging these messages keep repeating as I keep connecting in prompt

```
D/ZrHung.AppEyeUiProbe: not watching, wait.
D/ZrHung.AppEyeUiProbe: restart watching
D/ZrHung.AppEyeUiProbe: not watching, wait.
D/ZrHung.AppEyeUiProbe: restart watching
```

My onClick calls

```
fun onConnectClick (view: View)
    {
        val wifiSpecs = WifiNetworkSpecifier.Builder()
            .setSsid("SSID")
            .setWpa2Passphrase("PASSWORD")
            .build()
        val networkRequest = NetworkRequest.Builder()
            .addTransportType(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_WIFI)
            .setNetworkSpecifier(wifiSpecs)
            .build()
        val connectivityManager = getSystemService((Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE)) as ConnectivityManager
        val networkCallback = ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback()

        connectivityManager.requestNetwork(networkRequest, networkCallback)
        Reply.text = "Connect Clicked"

    }
```

I have tried replacing

`val networkCallback = ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback()`

with

```
val networkCallback = object:ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback() {
            override fun onAvailable(network:Network) {
                super.onAvailable(network)
                connectivityManager.bindProcessToNetwork(network)
            }
```

as mentioned elsewhere but no change

The Full logcat output is:

```
I/e.myapplicatio: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
E/e.myapplicatio: Unknown bits set in runtime_flags: 0x8000
I/e.myapplicatio: Reinit property: dalvik.vm.checkjni= false
E/libc: Access denied finding property "runtime.mmitest.isrunning"
D/ActivityThread: Attach thread to application
W/ActivityThread: Application com.example.myapplication is waiting for the debugger on port 8100...
I/System.out: Sending WAIT chunk
I/System.out: Debugger has connected
I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
I/chatty: uid=10270(com.example.myapplication) identical 1 line
I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
I/System.out: debugger has settled (1421)
I/e.myapplicatio: QarthPatchMonintor::Init
I/e.myapplicatio: QarthPatchMonintor::StartWatch
I/e.myapplicatio: QarthPatchMonintor::WatchPackage: /data/hotpatch/fwkhotpatch/
I/e.myapplicatio: QarthPatchMonintor::CheckAndWatchPatch: /data/hotpatch/fwkhotpatch/com.example.myapplication
I/e.myapplicatio: QarthPatchMonintor::CheckAndWatchPatch: /data/hotpatch/fwkhotpatch/all
I/e.myapplicatio: QarthPatchMonintor::Run
I/e.myapplicatio: QarthPatchMonintor::Reading
I/e.myapplicatio: QarthPatchMonintor::CheckNotifyEvent
I/e.myapplicatio: QarthPatchMonintor::CheckNotifyEvent before read
I/HwApiCacheMangerEx: apicache path=/storage/emulated/0 state=mounted key=com.example.myapplication#10270#256
I/HwApiCacheMangerEx: apicache path=/storage/emulated/0 state=mounted key=com.example.myapplication#10270#0
I/AwareBitmapCacher: init processName:com.example.myapplication pid=24286 uid=10270
E/AwareLog: AtomicFileUtils: readFileLines file not exist: android.util.AtomicFile@88ec3a
E/AwareLog: AtomicFileUtils: readFileLines file not exist: android.util.AtomicFile@12270eb
V/ActivityThread: callActivityOnCreate
V/HwWidgetFactory: : successes to get AllImpl object and return....
I/OverScrollerOptimization: start init SmartSlideOverScroller and get the overscroller config
I/OverScrollerOptimization: get the overscroller config
W/e.myapplicatio: Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/View;->computeFitSystemWindows(Landroid/graphics/Rect;Landroid/graphics/Rect;)Z (greylist, reflection, allowed)
W/e.myapplicatio: Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/ViewGroup;->makeOptionalFitsSystemWindows()V (greylist, reflection, allowed)
D/ActivityThread: add activity client record, r= ActivityRecord{cf15e4 token=android.os.BinderProxy@5401765 {com.example.myapplication/com.example.myapplication.MainActivity}} token= android.os.BinderProxy@5401765
W/HiTouch_HiTouchSensor: depended package hiTouch does n't exist!
I/HiTouch_HiTouchSensor: HiTouch restricted: system app HiTouch don't exist.
D/HiTouch_PressGestureDetector: onAttached, package=com.example.myapplication, windowType=1, mHiTouchRestricted=true
I/iGraphics: [0020080c] pn: com.example.myapplication, p: 24286
I/iGraphics: [0030080c] no spt app: com.example.myapplication
D/mali_winsys: EGLint new_window_surface(egl_winsys_display *, void *, EGLSurface, EGLConfig, egl_winsys_surface **, EGLBoolean) returns 0x3000
W/Gralloc3: mapper 3.x is not supported
I/HwViewRootImpl: removeInvalidNode jank list is null
D/AwareBitmapCacher: handleInit switch not opened pid=24286
I/HwViewRootImpl: removeInvalidNode all the node in jank list is out of time
V/AudioManager: querySoundEffectsEnabled...
D/ConnectivityManager: requestNetwork and the calling app is: com.example.myapplication
D/ZrHung.AppEyeUiProbe: not watching, wait.
D/ZrHung.AppEyeUiProbe: restart watching
D/HwFrameworkSecurityPartsFactory: HwFrameworkSecurityPartsFactory in.
I/HwFrameworkSecurityPartsFactory: add HwFrameworkSecurityPartsFactory to memory.
W/libEGL: EGLNativeWindowType 0x7c3502cc10 disconnect failed
D/mali_winsys: EGLint new_window_surface(egl_winsys_display *, void *, EGLSurface, EGLConfig, egl_winsys_surface **, EGLBoolean) returns 0x3000
D/ZrHung.AppEyeUiProbe: not watching, wait.
W/libEGL: EGLNativeWindowType 0x7c3502cc10 disconnect failed
D/ZrHung.AppEyeUiProbe: restart watching
D/mali_winsys: EGLint new_window_surface(egl_winsys_display *, void *, EGLSurface, EGLConfig, egl_winsys_surface **, EGLBoolean) returns 0x3000
I/HwViewRootImpl: removeInvalidNode all the node in jank list is out of time
W/libEGL: EGLNativeWindowType 0x7c26c4b750 disconnect failed
D/ZrHung.AppEyeUiProbe: not watching, wait.
```

Full code can be found [here](https://github.com/CurtisHorton/NetworkConnectExample)

EDIT: Apparently this is a known issue [link1](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/170406306) [link2](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/143549613) with some OEM hardware

Comment: Do you see anything interesting in `logcat` for `ConnectivityService`?

Comment: I edited my question with the full logcat output. Nothing jumps outs at me as an obvious source of the problem. However I believe it has to do with a known issue where the network request is released as soon as it connects and a new request is initiated. So far I have found 2 bug reports related to this, I've added the links in the question